# Most natural way to indicate time spent doing something?

Tags: choix-de-mot

If I wanted to say, for instance, "I waited for two days," what would be the most natural way of phrasing it? *J'ai passé deux journées en attendant* ? *J'ai attendu pendant deux journées* ? A second example might be "I walked for three hours" -- again, how best to phrase that?

Comment: You should also look for the difference between "*jour*" and "*journée*". You don't need to ask a question, there are already plenty here.

Comment: I am familiar with the difference; my understanding was that in this context if you wished to emphasize the duration you used the longer form. If I'm emphasizing that I waited two whole days, is *journée* still not the right word?

Comment: Nope ! It's almost never a good idea to use "*journée*" with specific numbers (except "une" of course). It's ok when it's indefinite ("*des journées*"). "*En attendant*" is also no good (again, there a tons of questions about gerunds, we don't use them half as much as "-ing verbs" in English).

Comment: Exactly, but for one day, "journée" is fine : if you spent the whole day shopping, you'll say "J'ai passé la journée à faire du shopping", alors que "J'ai passé le jour à faire du shopping" est incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the following are the most natural ways to say that:

> J'ai passé deux jours à attendre.
>
> J'ai attendu (pendant) deux jours.

where the *pendant* is optional.

Then:

> J'ai marché (pendant) trois heures.

*Pendant* is again optional.

Comment: You can also say "*Ça fait deux jours que j'attends*" if you really want emphasis on the "two days".